# C# Custom Attributes - How to use them as functionnality tools

Tags: c#, dll, compilation, custom-attributes

Sorry for the abstract title i don't know how to phrase it myself...

i am making a small networking framework, what i would like to do is to be able to register methodes inside a list so that i am able to call them with an index, i'd also like to be able to register them after having built the dll so it can be used in other projects, so it has to be loosely coupled aswell.

Not being happy with a simple but clunky register method i thought about using Custom Attributes, i have seen them being used in heavy frameworks to add meta data but more surprisingly add functionality to what it is applied to.

So essentially what i would like is to be able to add an attribute to any method and for this tagged method to add it self to the method list at some event (preferably at compile time to avoid performence issues at runtime), for example :

```
[Command]
public void DisconnectPlayer(Player player)
{
   // Logic here
}
```

Is what i said possible ?

Comment: Consider reading about the MEF framework.

Answer (score 0):

I have used custom attributes to identify work processes for a dynamic dispatch system before. Dynamic dispatch is necessary if you want your controller to pass parameters to each function and handle return types, along with cycle detection and resolving same-named methods. In short, that's the hard way to create controllable processes. Yes you can achieve multiple inheritance this way.

If you're asking about building custom attributes, you'll use Reflection to fetch their values. You'll need to organize how your methods are represented in your project to write an algorithm to detect them at run-time and build the list.

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)] // or Method, Property, etc.
    public class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public string Instruction { get; set; }
    }

    // example class
    [MyCustomAttribute (Instruction = "Command")]
    public class ReportRow { ... }

    void OrganizeProcesses()
    {
        foreach (var propertyInfo in this.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            object[] attribute = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyCustomAttribute), true);
            if (attribute.Length > 0)
            {
                var myAttribute = (MyCustomAttribute)attribute[0];
                if (String.Compare(propertyInfo.Instruction, "Command") == 0)
                    // e.g. assign method to dictionary, unless its signature is there.
            }
        }
    }
```

Custom attributes allow us to hardcode metadata like identifiers, and so this works. However, I have a whole process architecture for custom processes which does way more out of the box with minimum code.

A process you can assemble, extend and reshape any way you want to is known in manufacturing as a **mass customization** system. The trick to organizing production processes is to not deliver data. My architecture models hardcoded and dynamic forms. But the rules for organizing and managing collaborative (production) processes are complex, and so you should study every aspect of my system at my website http://www.powersemantics.com/.

Here's how my architecture answers your requirement for "registering methods in a list to call them with an index." Processes consist of custom machines, classes containing only an M() method and references to the data points they operate on. Custom machines don't need dynamic dispatch, because they don't communicate parameters. They are bound by reference to the properties of whatever DTO needs processing. They fetch data from the heap themselves. Therefore, a controller can simply execute its active routing list of machines. Welcome to total control.

```
   public class MyProduct
   {
       public Cvar<int> X { get; set; }
   }
   public class MyCustomMachine : Producer<MyProduct>, IMachine
   {
       public void M() { ... }
   }
```

Your immediate problem may be to control execution by an index, but this architecture solves every later controllability problem:  interrupting and resuming, extending and changing those processes, associating parts with either the UI or business layer for BackgroundWorker, injecting control steps or default setting steps or subprocess steps dynamically, etc.

In short, POWER is every design pattern at once.